# can i swap individual words in a text area?

Tags: php, html

I have a text are that displays some user inputted text, what i aim to do is a simple translation?

For example could i swap all uses of the word dog for cat?

There will be lots of words to do, so would there be a quicker way using php, html or another language to do this, maybe streamwriter/reader?

this is the box that will show what the user has inputted:

```
<div align="center">
<form method="GET" action="translate.php">
<textarea name="status2" cols="50" rows="5"<input type="text"/>
<?php echo $status ?>
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="post to wall" />
</form>

</div>
```

any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Unrelated Note: The past couple of questions i have posted did not initially let me post as they did not meet the quality standards, where can i find the quality standards?

Comment: Standards can be found in the **[FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)**

Comment: you'll want [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can handle this easily.

```
<?php echo str_replace('dog','cat',$status); ?>
```

First word is item to search for, second word is what to replace it with, third item is what to search within.

**EDIT**

As requested, an example of how to make it usable for a lot of items and not case-sensitive. First, make a PHP function:

```
function replaceWords($existing,$new,$content){
    str_ireplace($existing,$new,$content);
}
```

Then make arrays for all the words to find and all the words to replace (with the same order):

```
$existing_array = array('dog','elephant','bird');
$new_array = array('cat','eagle','your mom');
// dog replaced with cat, elephant replaced with eagle, bird replaced with your mom
```

Then use a `for` loop to call the function:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 150; $i++){
    function replaceWords($existing_array[$i],$new_array[$i],$status);
}
```

I did 150 because you said about that number, but the exact number of words should go there. That should do it.

[More info can be found here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

**SECOND EDIT**

An even more automated `for` loop:

```
$cnt = count($existing_array); // you can use either array, since they're the same length
for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++){
    function replaceWords($existing_array[$i],$new_array[$i],$status);
}
```

This way you just need to add items to the arrays, and the new word count will be the new length of the `for` loop. Less manual code the better.

Comment: brilliant, is there anyway to modify it so it is not case sensitive?

Comment: what would be the easiest way to replace alot of words? im going to have approx 150 in total.

Comment: convert this into a function and call it for each one. i'll mod my answer to show.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the below function, you can replace any work in a case in-sensitive manner:

`str_ireplace ( "dog", "cat", $status );`

If you want to replace multiple words, you can use arrays:

`str_ireplace ( array('dog', 'mouse'), array('cat', 'hamster'), $status );`

The array example will replace the words in the same index, e.g. `dog` will be replaced with `cat`, and `mouse` will be replaced with `hamster`.